# How to access profile restrict login hours

Tags: apex, soql, rest-api, tooling-api

How can I check the login hours of a user profile that configured in user's profile?

I have looked into `LoginHours` but could not find.

In which `object/soql/apex/rest/tooling api` it would be available to use in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this information via the `Tooling API` if you query it for [`Profile`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_profile.htm).

Sample query:

```
/services/data/v41.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+Metadata+FROM+Profile+LIMIT+1
```

Sample structure:

```js
{
    "size": 1,
    "totalSize": 1,
    "done": true,
    "queryLocator": null,
    "entityTypeName": "Profile",
    "records": [{
        "attributes": {
            "type": "Profile",
            "url": "/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/Profile/00e..."
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "applicationVisibilities": [],
            "categoryGroupVisibilities": null,
            "classAccesses": [],
            "custom": true,
            "customPermissions": [],
            "description": null,
            "externalDataSourceAccesses": [],
            "fieldPermissions": [],
            "loginHours": null,
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the key you are looking for
            "loginIpRanges": [],
            ...
        }
    }]
}
```

So a simple structure will allow you to deserialize the results:

```
class QueryResult
{
    List<ProfileResult> records;
}
class ProfileResult
{
    ProfileMetadata metadata;
}
class ProfileMetadata
{
    LoginHours loginHours;
}
class LoginHours
{
    Integer sundayStart, sundayEnd;
    Integer mondayStart, mondayEnd;
    Integer tuesdayStart, tuesdayEnd;
    Integer wednesdayStart, wednesdayEnd;
    Integer thursdayStart, thursdayEnd;
    Integer fridayStart, fridayEnd;
    Integer saturdayStart, saturdayEnd;
}
```

And here's a sample anonymous script which makes use of that structure:

```
String auth = 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId();
String query = 'SELECT Metadata FROM Profile LIMIT 1';
String endpoint = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() +
    '/services/data/v41.0/tooling/query/?q=' +
    EncodingUtil.urlEncode(query, 'UTF-8');

HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setHeader('Authorization', auth);
request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
request.setMethod('GET');

HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
QueryResult result = (QueryResult)JSON.deserialize(
    response.getBody(), QueryResult.class
);
ProfileResult record = result.records[0];
system.debug(record.Metadata.loginHours);
system.debug(record.Metadata.loginHours.mondayStart);
system.debug(record.Metadata.loginHours.mondayEnd);
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian, you have provided more than what I asked for. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Adrian , Thanks for the retrieval feature above, my requirement is to set login hours programatically, do you have any suggestion for that ?

Comment: @Quddus that is a notably different and non-trivial question. Please pose it as a `Question`, not a `Comment`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson : I did that already thanks - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/340318/how-to-access-and-set-login-hours-programatically-for-a-given-profile

Answer (score 3):

You can access the Profile LoginHours via the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm) or the Tooling API.

E.g. with the Tooling API under the [`Metadata`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_profile.htm) field.

**GET** `/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/Profile/00e0g0000010DMr`

[image]

The [ProfileLoginHours](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm#ProfileLoginHours_title) format is described in the Metadata API.

> Valid values for Start: the number of minutes since midnight. Must be evenly divisible by 60 (full hours). For example, 300 is 5:00 a.m.